# The relation between Frechet derivative and differentiation in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, derivatives, frechet-derivative

In the book of *Complex Made Simple* by Ullrich, at page 4, it is given that

[image]

[image]

However, if we are considering $\mathbb{C} = \mathbb{R}^2$, then $Df$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix, and not a complex number, but when we consider use the "complex differentiation", $f'(x)$ is a complex numbers, so is the author claiming that

$$T(h) = a * h, \quad a \in \mathbb{C} = \mathbb{R}^2, \quad T: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C} \quad \text{and $T$ is $\mathbb{R}-linear$} $$
for any *unit* $h \in \mathbb{C}$ ?

Comment: Well, from the excerpt, all he is saying is that the notion of differentiation with respect to a complex scalar is different to differentiating with respect to $\mathbb{R}^2$. Of course, you can express any complex differentiable function as the latter, in which case $Df(z)$ will be a $2 \times 2$ matrix that corresponds to multiplication by a complex scalar, and hence has a very restrictive format (cf. the Cauchy Riemann equations). But the existence of $Df(z)$ in general does not mean that the function has a complex differentiable equivalent.

Comment: @copper.hat what do you mean by "complex differentiable equivalent" ?

Comment: Every complex differentiable $f$ can be written as an $\mathbb{R}^2$ differentiable $f$, but not vice versa. The matrix $Df(x)$  will look like $\begin{bmatrix} u_x & -v_x \\ v_x & u_x \end{bmatrix}$. The function $f(x,y) = x^2+y^2$ does not have a complex equivalent (otherwise the Cauchy Riemann equations would not hold).

Comment: @copper.hat First of all, thanks for your responses; however, you comment does focus on different points than that I'm raising in my question. Plus, I have just started Complex Analysis, and no idea what Cauchy-Riemann equation is.